# Academic cv items: chronological order or most recent first?

Tags: cv, writing-style

I'm curious about the common practices. I'm compiling an (academic) cv. Should I order items chronologically or place the most recent first? What are the considerations?

**Edit:** And does the recommendation extend to publications and presentations too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the UK I've always seen it done in reverse chronological order (most recent first). This may vary from country to country.

[A](http://theprofessorisin.com/2012/01/12/dr-karens-rules-of-the-academic-cv/) [few](https://www.elsevier.com/connect/writing-an-effective-academic-cv) [links](http://www.theguardian.com/higher-education-network/blog/2013/nov/01/academic-cv-job-10-mistakes) [seem](http://Publications:%20a%20reverse%20chronological%20list%20is%20a%20prerequisite,%20best%20presented%20as%20an%20appendix.%20Include%20journal%20articles,%20books%20or%20chapters%20of%20books,%20reports%20and%20patents%20Research%20experience:%20in%20reverse%20chronological%20order.%20Emphasise%20specialist/technical%20expertise,%20IT%20skills,%20plus%20any%20skills%20required%20for%20the%20job.%20including%20project%20and%20people%20management%20Education:%20in%20reverse%20chronological%20order.%20Focus%20on%20higher%20education%20onwards.%20Include%20awards%20and%20scholarships.%20Include%20the%20name%20of%20your%20doctoral%20supervisor%20and%20funding%20body,%20if%20appropriate) to indicate that reverse chronological CVs are the norm. The last link there seems to break it down well, element by element.

And for the record, mine is also reverse chronological.

> Publications: a reverse chronological list is a prerequisite, best presented as an appendix. Include journal articles, books or chapters of books, reports and patents
>   Research experience: in reverse chronological order. Emphasise specialist/technical expertise, IT skills, plus any skills required for the job. including project and people management
>   Education: in reverse chronological order. Focus on higher education onwards. Include awards and scholarships. Include the name of your doctoral supervisor and funding body, if appropriate

Comment: +1 Ditto for my field (Philosophy, US). The reverse chronology standard lets people see what you've been up to recently, as opposed to the stuff you first published as a grad student maybe 15 years or more ago.

Comment: It makes perfect sense! I've gladly reordered my cv to reverse chronological. Many thanks!

Comment: Of course! And if you can, ask a friend or colleague to show you theirs. Academic CVs can be confusing (especially if you've accomplished a lot of stuff), and comparing your CV to somebody else's can be very reassuring.